# Buttons not centering in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a jsFiddle here, please open in Internet Explorer and in one other major browser:

http://jsfiddle.net/6bv7j/1/

Now in the jsFiddle, just click on the "Add Question" button, and it will append a row underneath. In the row it shows two buttons, one known as "Select All Answers" and other known as "Remove All Answers".

Now in the major browser, the buttons are centered in the table which is fine. But in Internet Explorer it is not centered, it is still aligned to the left. Is there a piece of code which is causing it to not center in Internet Explorer or do I need to add something in order to be able to center it in Internet Explorer?

I tried `float:center`, but this did not work. I'm not sure if it's best to use the `align` method.

Below is the CSS and jQuery/HTML of the code:

```
.allBtnsRow{
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:85%;
}

.allRemoveBtnsRow{
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:85%;
}
```

Below is jQuery/HTML code:

```
$BtnsClass = $("<input class='allBtnsRow btnsAll' type='button' value='Select All Answers' onClick='selectAll(this);' /><br/><input class='allRemoveBtnsRow btnsRemove' type='button' value='Remove All Answers' onClick='removeAll(this);' />");
```

Comment: try with `body{text-align: center;}` which can center your all body part.

Comment: The debug console in IE is not useful?

Comment: @JanDvorak How do I use IE console for debug as I never used IE console before

Comment: @jogesh_p I don't want whole body to center but which individual element can I center?

Comment: @user1930247 open the console with `F12`, then use as a normal developer console. The pointer icon selects an element by clicking and shows it in the DOM tree.

Comment: It seems as if buttons don't behave like inline elements in IE.

Comment: @JanDvorak So do I probably need to display:block for buttons then margin: 0 auto;?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `tr and td` inside a `div`. Remove `$row` and `$cell` and append `$BtnClass` to `$answer`:

```
// $row = $("<tr/>").appendTo($answer);
// $cell = $("<td/>").appendTo($row);

$BtnsClass = $("<input class='allBtnsRow btnsAll' type='button' value='Select All Answers' onClick='selectAll(this);' /><br/><input class='allRemoveBtnsRow btnsRemove' type='button' value='Remove All Answers' onClick='removeAll(this);' />");

$BtnsClass.appendTo($answer);
```

Comment: Hi, I will need the <tr>, <td> tags

Comment: Should I change the div tags to <tr> tags instead?

Comment: @user1930247 its coming like <tr><td><div><tr><td></td></tr></div></td></tr> which is invalid html format.

Comment: What is the best way of replacing the <div> tag?

Comment: having a div inside a td is valid. But why do you need a tr and td inside div?

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if the structure you're creating is "ideal", but I've made some changes to the `.answer` CSS, given your existing structure:

#### CSS

```
.answer
{
    width: 110px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/6bv7j/4/

Comment: Hi, I need the width to be 100%, when I tried you method with 100% width then it doesn't align to center